# Meaning of “show out” (intransitive form, NOT show someone out)

Tags: meaning, british-english

In [a video about undercover police work](https://youtu.be/Q-AQ9DCoKQ8), the expression to “show out” comes back twice:

> No wonder he got shot, to be honest.  Mind you he showed out, didn’t he?  Golden rule.
> [[3:46](https://youtu.be/Q-AQ9DCoKQ8?t=226)]

> You never break cover.  The golden rule is you never show out. [[10:43](https://youtu.be/Q-AQ9DCoKQ8?t=643)]

I’m pretty sure I’ve never seen this used without a complement (e.g. I’ve seen “show someone out” but this is visibly different). I’m not sure I understand it fully, is it just synonymous with breaking cover? Is it a colloquial way of saying “showing your hand”? Am I missing some subtlety? The speaker is English, if that’s relevant.

Any dictionary I’ve consulted only mentions the transitive form, i.e. show [sb] out:

- [wordreference](https://www.wordreference.com/enfr/show%20out)
- [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/show-sb-out?q=show+out)
- [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/show%20out)

Just to name a few. This question also did not appear elsewhere in the English SE nor the English Language Learners SE.

Comment: I suspect the answer is in the second example. Never show out = never break cover, that is, never give away that you're police.

Comment: Kind of weird closing this as off-topic. It certainly isn’t a common way of using “show out”, so definitely not on topic for ELL, and the definition is also missing in all dictionaries I’ve checked (I’ve edited in a few to *show research*). @DjinTonic’s answer is great and points out this is colloquial hence the difficulty in pinning down the exact meaning.

Comment: Not weird at all. There was no research shown until your edit. // I believe '[English] Wiktionary' has the largest listing of headwords among English dictionaries, and, especially where a colloquial / informal / slang usage is suspected, is always worth checking.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Sorry, I went by [this recommendation](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5039/how-much-research-is-needed) and examples linked in there. Is there some more up-to-date guidance to use? I’ll make sure to check wiktionary as well next time.

Comment: "It's perfectly reasonable for reviewers to assume that a common expression can be explained by consulting ordinary reference works. They shouldn't have to do that search. If it can't be, it's up to the asker to demonstrate that it can't be. Something like "I researched but maybe I missed it" isn't particularly helpful in this case: if you researched and didn't find anything, at least show where you looked." (Andrew Leach). It is only reasonable to extend this to potential broadened usages of common words / phrases (as with "Is 'very unique' acceptable?" "Can 'telescope' mean 'observe with ...

Comment: a telescope?" "Can 'show out' be used as an **intransitive** multi word verb?" As you've now added correctly attributed and linked research (showing 'no support for this usage here' ... still totally acceptable evidence of research), it's a valid question on ELU and I've voted to reopen the edited version.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth My bad. I assumed on my side it was obvious this was an uncommon expression, my edits tried to make clearer what I meant. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Before looking this up, I got the meaning of the OP's example from context. However, I wasn't familiar with this usage. From "The cuffs of your dress shirt should show out from/out of your jacket sleeves" I wouldn't blink at "The cuffs of your dress shirt should show out"-- not so for "Don't show out in company" (show off/act up/act out) or "Keep you head down, or you'll show out (to the enemy). This is new for me.

Comment: I don't really see the point of a question like this. If you actually worked in police undercover activities, I'm sure you'd pick up on the usage on day one of your training (it is after all the ***golden rule*** that you mustn't ***show out***). If you don't work in that area there's probably no reason why you should need to think about it, *if the intended sense isn't obvious when you encounter it somewhere*.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about a domain-specific slang usage

Comment: @FumbleFingers I disagree. The usage is not limited to police work and reference works cover the usage.

Comment: @DjinTonic Well, as just commented and voted, I disagree with your definition ***and*** the question!

Comment: The usages are fairly continuous from just appearing/revealing oneself to acting up to showing off. This is confirmed by the **OED definition** I've added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**show out** (v.)

> (intransitive, colloquial, informal, slang) To display or present
> oneself; represent. [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/show_out)

> To present oneself, especially in a public or performative manner.
> *The pop star always shows out with incredibly extravagant, often  outrageous, outfits.*
>
> To perform some task with as much energy, enthusiasm, and
> determination as possible.
> *It's going to be tough to win today's game, but if we all show out, we can accomplish anything!* [Farlex Dictionary of Idioms](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/show+yourself+out)

> *intransitive*. **To become visible, discernible, or apparent**; to be revealed. Now somewhat rare. In early use also: **to project, stick out**.
>
> *A little later the flicker of their camp-fire showed out.*
>
> *intransitive*. Originally and chiefly U.S. regional (southern and south Midland). = **to show off**.  OED

---

> He should have trusted his *Star Wars*-style instinct and his eyes and
> ears on the three occasions his surveillance team has, in the
> parlance, **'showed out'**—the times when he has spotted or 'got on to'
> the fact that he was being tracked and watched. [Graham Johnson;
> *Druglord*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Druglord/-9H0vtBoIGUC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22showed%20out%22%20spotted&pg=PT126&printsec=frontcover)

> We couldn't park too close to the gates without **showing out**, which
> made identifying container numbers as they left the facility
> impossible. [Harry Ferguson; *Kilo 17*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Kilo_17/USZxmK9XX8UC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22showing%20out%22%20and%20was%20seen&pg=PT146&printsec=frontcover)

> The rabbits, too, were **showing out** among the grass, scuttling
> about busily. [Henry Kingsley; *Ravenshoe*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Ravenshoe/rMD0DwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22showing%20out%22%20and%20was%20seen&pg=PA356&printsec=frontcover)

> The two of us got on that dance floor and **showed out**. Our dance
> moves were off the chart, and people started clapping for us and moved
> off. [Jeanette Tyson; *Shhhhh...Don't Tell.....*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Shhhhh_Don_t_Tell/j--NDAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22showed%20out%22%20and%20was%20spotted&pg=PT133&printsec=frontcover)

> "Mama, you need to whip that boy" He needs a good whippin'! You should
> have seen how he carried on and **showed out** and pestered me!
> [Claude Eubanks; *Bully in the Pulpit*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Bully_in_the_Pulpit/zNU6LkNS3nYC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22showed%20out%22%20and%20was%20seen&pg=PA155&printsec=frontcover)

> Of course he didn't tell anyone, but he fumbled around at dinner and
> spilled food on his clothes and blubbered when asked anything. It was
> like he went into a stupor. Alex and Tom laughed at John and thought
> he was just **showing out** and left it at that. [T. Burns and D.
> Burns; *The Young Scots*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/THE_YOUNG_SCOTS/ReXqAwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22showing%20out%22%20and%20was%20seen&pg=PA152&printsec=frontcover)

> "Nobody said anything about being undercover, I just don't feel the
> need to **show out**. I'm not all about trying to get someone's
> attention..." [J.B.M. Patrick; *Angelos Odyssey*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Angelos_Odyssey/ns--DwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=was%20undercover%20and%20couldn%27t%20%22show%20out%22&pg=PT266&printsec=frontcover)

Comment: I think you're confusing the relatively rare usage *to show out = to show **off***

Comment: No, "show out: verb to behave ostentatiously" [*New Partridge Dictionary of Slang*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_New_Partridge_Dictionary_of_Slang_an/bbcBCgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=partridge+%22show+out%22&pg=PA2006&printsec=frontcover) but that's just one meaning.

Comment: Intransitive 'represent' is unusual.